# How to reload the UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiviewcontroller

Can anyone please tell me how to reload the view.In my program,it contain a tab view controller.There is one item named "A" in the tab.And this "A" item is pointing to a viewController.In that view Controller, it is displaying some datas and I have included UIActionSheet in that. There is one button-Delete in the actionsheet.This delete button is for deleting the particular data.Now my problem is that I need to reload that view so that these deleted data should not be displayed. So anyone please tell me how to reload the page. I have included the following code before

```
[self presentModalViewController:historyView animated:YES];
[historyView setNeedsDisplay];
```

but it is showing some error :-

```
 No visible @interface for viewcontroller declares the selector 'setNeedsDisplay'
```

Please tell me the solution.. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UIViewController** class doesn't have a method **setNeedsDisplay**. The **UIView** class does have this method. So you can write like that:

```
[historyView.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

But this method doesn't reload a view. It just marks the receiver’s entire bounds rectangle as needing to be redrawn (from apple documentation [iOS Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)). So as a result the **drawRect** method will be called.

To solve your problem you can create your own function like *initializeUI* in your view controller and then call it when the view is loaded initially (in **viewDidLoad** method) and for example after deleting the data when you need the view to be updated.